# Can't install dotnet watcher tools on dotnetcore 2.1.105

Tags: .net-core, nuget-package-restore, file-watcher

I installed .NET Core 2.1.105 on ubuntu from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux)
 and created the sample web api project with `dotnet new api-test`

Then I tried to add the dotnet watcher package with

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools
```

And when I issue a `dotnet restore` I get the following error:

```
$ dotnet restore
  Restoring packages for ~/devel/apps/dotnet/api_test/api_test.csproj...
  Restore completed in 101.8 ms for ~/devel/apps/dotnet/api_test/api_test.csproj.
~/devel/apps/dotnet/api_test/api_test.csproj : error NU1605: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.NETCore.App from 2.0.6 to 2.0.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
~/devel/apps/dotnet/api_test/api_test.csproj : error NU1605:  api_test -> Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools 2.0.1 -> Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.0.6) 
~/devel/apps/dotnet/api_test/api_test.csproj : error NU1605:  api_test -> Microsoft.NETCore.App (>= 2.0.0)
  Restore failed in 1.26 sec for ~/devel/apps/dotnet/api_test/api_test.csproj.
```

And this is my `.csproj` file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="2.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

-- update

as stated in the answers bellow, dotnet watch should be included be part of he SDK from version 2.1, so I did this little test:

```
$ dotnet --version
2.1.105
$ dotnet new webapi -o tmp_api
The template "ASP.NET Core Web API" was created successfully.
$ cd tmp_api/
$ dotnet watch run
No executable found matching command "dotnet-watch"
```

--

dotnet watch is available from preview2 version onwards (which is available [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/thank-you/dotnet-sdk-2.1.300-preview2-linux-x64-binaries))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from [.NET Core 2.1 Preview 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/04/11/announcing-net-core-2-1-preview-2/) the CLI tools like `dotnet watch` are now part of the SDK:

> We found that these tools were so popular that having to add them to individual projects didn’t seem like the right design, so we made them part of the SDK.
>
> These tools were previously `DotNetCliToolReference` tools. They are no longer delivered that way. You can delete the `DotNetCliToolReference` entries in your project file when you adopt .NET Core 2.1.

Comment: I updated the question, `dotnet watch` doesn't seem to be working out of the box

Comment: @opensas the current latest Preview 2 version is [2.1.300-preview2-008533](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/sdk-2.1.300-preview2) and `dotnet watch run` works for me. Not sure that 2.1.105 contains those changes

Answer (score 1):

`dotnet watch` is a CLI tool, not a package your code can depend on. The [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-2.0#add-dotnet-watch-to-a-project) explain that you need to use `DotNetCliToolReference`:

```
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
```

You shouldn't be using it as a `PackageReference`.